# WPF: Drawing a line on MouseMove purely in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mousemove, polyline

I am new to WPF and I was wondering if I could draw a line that updated with mouse position purely in XAML?

I know I can do:

```
...
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
   <Polyline x:Name="MyLine" Points="0,0 1,1" Stroke=1 />
</Canvas>
...
```

Than in C#

```
private void MyCanvas_MouseMove(...)
{
   if(!DrawFlag)
       return;

   Point Pos = new Point();
   Pos = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
   MyLine.Points[ MyLine.Points.Count - 1 ] = Pos;
}
```

Is there a way to have a flag set, DrawFlag, and then have the point position update using only XAML code? I get a feeling the answer may be in creating a Template but not really sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to draw on a canvas purely with XAML using an `InkCanvas`

```
<InkCanvas />
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that purely in XAML. XAML is a presentation language, not a "real" programming language.